# Unit Test for DAO class: Java Spring MVC using Hibernate and H2 database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I am trying to write jUnit test for my DAO class and am getting error when run the following test in eclipse:

```
package com.bookstore.dao;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;    
import com.bookstore.domain.Book;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:**/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class BookDaoImplTest {

    private BookDao bookDao;
    private Book book;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        book = new Book();
        book.setBookName("Some Book Name");
        book.setBookCategory("Fiction");
        book.setBookPrice(11.11);
        // more properties here (not relevant for the question)
    }

    @Test
    @Rollback(true)
    public void testBookInsert() {
        bookDao.bookInsert(book);  // nullPointer happens at this line!
        final int bookId = book.getBookId();
        Book insertedBook = bookDao.getBookById(bookId);    
        Assert.assertEquals(insertedBook.getBookName(), book.getBookName());
    }
}
```

Also my DAO implementation class is as follows:

```
package com.bookstore.dao;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import com.bookstore.domain.Book;
import com.bookstore.exception.BookNotFoundException;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class BookDaoImpl implements BookDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session = null;

    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Book");
        List<Book> books = query.list();
        session.flush();
        return books;
    }

    public Book getBookById(int bookId) {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Book bookById = (Book) session.get(Book.class, bookId);
        session.flush();
        if (bookById == null) {
            throw new BookNotFoundException(bookId);
        }
        return bookById;
    }

    public void bookInsert(Book book) {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(book);
        session.flush();
    }

    // more methods here (not relevant for the question)
}
```

I have also created **applicationContext-test.xml** under the folder **src/test/resources** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.Dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list><value>com.bookstore</value></list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Now the error I am getting in the JUnit window is `NullPointerException` at line `bookDao.bookInsert(book);` of my test:

[JUnit window of Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhpBB.png)

And in the console I can see the following:

```
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Dec 08, 2016 10:16:41 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@23529fee] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Dec 08, 2016 10:16:41 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5dfcfece: startup date [Thu Dec 08 22:16:38 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: making session an instance variable is a mistake, threads can access the session or overwrite the reference to it concurrently.

Comment: try to add `@Autowired` for `bookDao`

Comment: Nathan, do you mean I should have `Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` in every method instead of an instance variable `private Session session = null;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your *applicationContext.xml* file is not on the classpath of your unit test. Try copying it to resources folder of your test package.

Or you are already creating the dao yourself in @Before setup method, why are you also using @Autowired?

Comment: I created another file - applicationContext-test.xml under the folder src/test/resources and removed @Autowired annotation. Looks like test is trying to run, but still with errors. When I debuged - the null pointer is thrown at line `session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` of my BookDaoImpl class.

Comment: how are you configuring your session factory? if its in an xml file it may also be missing from the classpath

Comment: session factory is configured in `applicatioContext-test.xml` file which is located under the folder `src/test/resources`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way your created the BookDao instance in BookDaoImplTest. The only way for BookDao and the referenced beans inside it to be created correctly is through dependency injection (e.g. using @Autowired). If you create it manually by using the "new" operator or by mocking it, the fields like "sessionFactory" might be null (if you don't set them manually).

Comment: If I add `@Autowired` to `BookDao bookDao;` I will get the error: `SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@64616ca2] to prepare test instance [com.bookstore.dao.BookDaoImplTest@27494e46]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bookstore.dao.BookDaoImplTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found ...`

Comment: so it means spring cannot find your applicationContext-test.xml. In your BookDaoImplTest, you can try to replace `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:**/applicationContext-test.xml"})` with `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-test.xml"})`